# Performance issue in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to improve performance of my stored procedure. Please find my stored procedure below which works fine, but it takes more than 5 minutes for some time not always to get the result due to that it's causing timeout from API.

Please note: `@Include` and `@BeginDate` are the stored procedure input parameters:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate datetime ='2023-09-28'
DECLARE @from datetime
DECLARE @to datetime
DECLARE @Include BIT = 1

SET @from = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @BeginDate), 0)
SET @to = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, @BeginDate), 0)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#results') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #results

CREATE TABLE #results 
(
    [BPID] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [DId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Number] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [Account] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [LineOfBusinessDesc] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [LineOfBusiness] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [Channel] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [ProductLine] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [BusinessSegment] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [LineOfBusinessType] [varchar](35) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #results
    SELECT 
        [PID], [DId], [Number], [Account],
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM 
        dbo.DailyDataInfo
    WHERE 
        CreatedDate >= @from 
        AND CreatedDate < @to

IF @Include = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #results
        SELECT 
            a.[PID], [DId], a.[Number], a.[Account],
            a.[LineOfBusiness], b.[LineOfBusiness],
            b.[Channel], b.[ProductLine], b.[BusinessSegment]
        FROM 
            dbo.OtherDailyData a
        OUTER APPLY 
            (SELECT TOP 1 Id, 
                 x.Data.value('(//Data/Company/LineOfBusiness)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS LineOfBusiness, 
                 x.Data.value('(//Data/Company/Channel)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS Channel, 
                 x.Data.value('(//Data/Company/ProductLine)[1]', 'varchar(25)') AS ProductLine, 
                 x.Data.value('(//Data/Company/BusinessSegment)[1]', 'varchar(25)') AS BusinessSegment, 
             FROM 
                 dbo.TermData x
             WHERE
                 x.Reference = a.Number
             ORDER BY
                 x.Id DESC) b
        WHERE 
            CreatedDate >= @from AND CreatedDate < @to
 END

 SELECT * FROM #results
```

This is the sample table data along with Index information for dbo.DailyDataInfo: I don't see any issue with this table, based on execution plan

`CreatedDate` – is the non-unique, non-clustered index. There are no other indexes on this table

```
BPID            Id  Number       Account    LineOfBusiness  Createddate
F886A11A6546199 1   9203919023  9203919023  HH              10/2/23 8:04 PM
1802063B1312516 2   9203919031  9203919031  KJ              10/2/23 8:04 PM
a4DEEF472650CB8 3   9203905782  9203905782  KJ              10/2/23 8:04 PM
05D23BE7D263582 4   9203908786  9203908786  HHH             10/2/23 8:04 PM
```

This is the sample table data along with Index information for `dbo.OtherDailyData`: I don't see any issue with this table, based on execution plan.

`Did`  is the primary Key and it is a clustered index. There are no other indexes on this table.

```
    BPId                DId         Number       CreatedDate
9FE25361398013BF    64  9340733736  10/2/23 8:05 PM
20C072C8596503A     68  9340732569  10/2/23 8:01 PM
6526588B6CFC49A     72  9340733502  10/2/23 8:02 PM
```

This is the sample table data along with Index information for `dbo.TermData` - I see issue with this table, based on execution plan

- `TermId` - is the primary key
- `Reference` - is the non-unique, non-clustered index

Data:

```
TermId  Reference  Data
------------------------------------------------------------------
321432  9340703401 This is the xml column please refer the below sample value
```

Data column value

```
<Data>
  <Allow>1</Allow>
  <EligibilityFlag>0</EligibilityFlag>
    <Company>
    <LineOfBusiness>CCC</LineOfBusiness>
    <LineOfBusinessType>
      <LOBType>CommercialAuto</LOBType>
    </LineOfBusinessType>
    <Channel />
    <ProductLine>Trad</ProductLine>
    <BusinessSegment>E</BusinessSegment>
  </Company>
  <Info>
    <Auditable>0</Auditable>
  </Info>
</Data>
```

Based on my analysis on execution plan, `TermData` table lookup is taking too much time, especially the XML lookup - 12% on each columns retrieval.

[![Execution plan][1]][1]

[![TermData Table][2]][2]

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: Thank you Dan, I have included the execution's plan link to my question

Comment: CreatedDate needs a index on it

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm not the best with reading execution plans, but can you tell if the WHERE logic limiting the dbo.OtherDailyData dataset is applying before or after the OUTER APPLY?

I feel like they should limit the dbo.OtherDailyData to the WHERE range before doing the OUTER APPLY; either with a CTE or nested table query.

Comment: Thank you Eric for your response, If i move where clause before the OUTER APPLY , it will throws an syntax error,  Here OUTER APPLY will throws an syntax error  . dbo.OtherDailyData a WHERE 
            CreatedDate >= from AND CreatedDate < to
  OUTER APPLY 
            (SELECT TOP 1 Id,

Comment: @user17824023 It shouldn't, so you're missing some additional change outside of what I'm suggesting. I went ahead and provided the total change as a response. Give it a go and see what happens. If it doesn't help, let me know and I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This moves the WHERE logic ahead of the OUTER APPLY...

```
DECLARE @BeginDate datetime ='2023-09-28'
DECLARE @from datetime
DECLARE @to datetime
DECLARE @Include BIT = 1

SET @from = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @BeginDate), 0)
SET @to = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, @BeginDate), 0)

SELECT  @from, @to

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#results') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #results

CREATE TABLE #results 
(
    [BPID] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [DId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Number] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [Account] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [LineOfBusinessDesc] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [LineOfBusiness] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [Channel] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [ProductLine] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [BusinessSegment] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [LineOfBusinessType] [varchar](35) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #results
    SELECT 
        [PID], [DId], [Number], [Account],
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM 
        dbo.DailyDataInfo
    WHERE 
        CreatedDate >= @from 
        AND CreatedDate < @to

IF @Include = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #results
        SELECT 
            a.[PID], [DId], a.[Number], a.[Account],
            a.[LineOfBusiness], b.[LineOfBusiness],
            b.[Channel], b.[ProductLine], b.[BusinessSegment], NULL
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT  n.[PID], n.[DId], n.[Number], 
                        n.[Account], n.[LineOfBusiness]
                FROM    dbo.OtherDailyData a
                WHERE 
                    CreatedDate >= @from AND CreatedDate < @to
            )   a
        OUTER APPLY 
            (SELECT TOP 1 Id, 
                 x.Data.value('(//Data/Company/LineOfBusiness)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS LineOfBusiness, 
                 x.Data.value('(//Data/Company/Channel)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS Channel, 
                 x.Data.value('(//Data/Company/ProductLine)[1]', 'varchar(25)') AS ProductLine, 
                 x.Data.value('(//Data/Company/BusinessSegment)[1]', 'varchar(25)') AS BusinessSegment
             FROM 
                 dbo.TermData x
             WHERE
                 x.Reference = a.Number
             ORDER BY
                 x.Id DESC) b        
 END

 SELECT * FROM #results
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for your time, however I tried implementing your suggestion , its throws an error in this statement  , INSERT INTO #results , this is the error - Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: You should always the the columns you are inserting into. But otherwise the error is self explanatory and you can easily solve it yourself.

Comment: In fact your own query should throw the same error, because you are inserting 9 columns into a 10 column table.

Comment: @user17824023 I made the changes so you won't receive that error anymore, but as was stated by someone else. Your original code shows you inserting 9 values instead of 10; it should be good now.

Comment: Thank you so  much Eric for your time and kind response. This helped for me

Answer (score 4):

First, don't use `//` in your XPATH.  It searches the whole document.  Instead path from the root `/` to exactly the node you need.  Then consider an [XML Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), or [materializing those three columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/promote-frequently-used-xml-values-with-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver16).

And watch this [classic video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/teched-2012/dbi404) where Michael Rys walks you through all the SQLXML best practices.

Comment: Thanks David for your comments, I agree with "//" suggestion. Regarding XML Index in my table I have already have Primary key as 'TermId', so in this case can I still change 'Data' xml column in dbo.TermData table as 'Primary XML Index' ?